# Video uploading on parse server android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio

I am a beginner in android, can someone provide me working tutorial on uploading a video from the mobile video gallery and saving it on parse server? Thanks in advance !
        `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("video/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull 
    String[] 
    permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) 
    {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
    grantResults);

    if (requestCode == 1) 
    {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
        {
            getPhoto();

        }
    }
   }


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
    {
        requestPermissions(new String[]
        {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    } else {
        getPhoto();
    }

   }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
    data) 
   {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==1 && resultCode==ChatActivity.RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            VideoView mVideo=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


            byte[] byteArray =stream.toByteArray();
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("resume.mp4", byteArray);

            ParseObject object = new ParseObject("Video");
            object.put("video",file);
            object.put("username", 
     ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
            object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() 
            {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) 
                {
                    if(e==null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,"Vidoe 
    Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,"Vidoe not 
    Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });

        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }`
```

I have given permission in manifest file for accessing the external data too !

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to use the `ParseFile` as described here [docs.parseplatform.org](http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#files) for your video.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out ! I tried working out using that ! But i get confused in my implementation. it will be great if i have some working tutorial to compare and re write my code !

Comment: If you have more specific questions it might be a good idea to ask them instead of asking for a full tutorial.

Comment: I have done some coding out there and it is not getting saved, can you help me?

Comment: Yes, its the code edited by me ! but i dont see its working !

Comment: Is it throwing an exception or is it just straight up not working? Is your file smaller than 10 Mb?

Comment: it doesnt throw any exception, but shows me time out in verbose ! its gives me a toast , video not saved and when i check my parse server , there is no objected created.Yes my file is mp4 which is 3 mb.

Comment: i have pasted the whole activity code for better understanding on how i am using intent and trying to upload the video ! please re check my code in the question once again !

Comment: I am able to upload , some path issues to the media folder ! Thanks

Comment: Good. You might want to mark the question as answered.